# Is there an automated way to remove XAML default properties?

Tags: wpf, xaml, optimization

Are there any automated tools that will parse through XAML code and clean out values that are explicitly declared to their defaults?

Example:

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
```

I would expect to be reduced to:

```
<Grid>
```

Comment: I'd be interested to know this as well, after seeing what Blend did to my markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kaxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/) has a scrubber feature that does this. Be careful with removing XAML default properties. Sometimes they are necessary for animation starting values.

Answer (score 0):

[XAML Power Toys](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/xaml-power-toys/) has a utility to remove designer generated XAML.  It is not specifically for items that are set to their default values, but it is close to what you are lookig for.